# CQL performance slow down due to 1 concurrent range request. Why?

Tags: cassandra

I am facing a performance issue after upgrading from 3.11.16 > 4.1.3 (inline upgrade).

For CQL Query - **select * from the table** with number of rows -  600 .

In Cassandra 3 the execution time was **3 seconds**
After upgrading to Cassandra 4, the execution time is **30 seconds**

The primary difference between Cassandra 3 and 4 , CQL trace log -

**In Cassandra 3, It's submitting multiple concurrent range requests -**

```
Submitted 14 concurrent range requests [Native-Transport-Requests-2] | 2024-01-24 09:56:16.973005 |  34.254.35.135 |        1122494 | 172.19.133.25
Submitted 4 concurrent range requests [Native-Transport-Requests-2] | 2024-01-24 09:56:17.045002 |  34.254.35.135 |        1194734 | 172.19.133.25
Submitted 127 concurrent range requests [Native-Transport-Requests-2] | 2024-01-24 09:56:17.266001 |  34.254.35.135 |        1414980 | 172.19.133.25
Submitted 24 concurrent range requests [Native-Transport-Requests-2] | 2024-01-24 09:56:17.721000 |  34.254.35.135 |        1869933 | 172.19.133.25
```

**In Cassandra 4, It's submitting a single concurrent range request -**

```
Submitting range requests on 392 ranges with a concurrency of 40 (0.9 rows per range expected) [Native-Transport-Requests-3] | 2024-02-05 12:00:58.228003 |  52.51.226.179 |       22912828 | 172.19.133.25
    Submitted 15 concurrent range requests [Native-Transport-Requests-3] | 2024-02-05 12:00:58.229046 |  52.51.226.179 |       22913465 | 172.19.133.25
    Submitted 20 concurrent range requests [Native-Transport-Requests-3] | 2024-02-05 12:00:58.299040 |  52.51.226.179 |       22983388 | 172.19.133.25
    Submitted 11 concurrent range requests [Native-Transport-Requests-3] | 2024-02-05 12:00:58.370060 |  52.51.226.179 |       23054887 | 172.19.133.25
    Submitted 10 concurrent range requests [Native-Transport-Requests-3] | 2024-02-05 12:00:58.440017 |  52.51.226.179 |       23124236 | 172.19.133.25
    Submitted 1 concurrent range requests [Native-Transport-Requests-3] | 2024-02-05 12:00:58.525007 |  52.51.226.179 |       23209641 | 172.19.133.25
    Submitted 1 concurrent range requests [Native-Transport-Requests-3] | 2024-02-05 12:00:58.594001 |  52.51.226.179 |       23278134 | 172.19.133.25
    Submitted 1 concurrent range requests [Native-Transport-Requests-3] | 2024-02-05 12:00:58.662006 |  52.51.226.179 |       23347013 | 172.19.133.25
    Submitted 1 concurrent range requests [Native-Transport-Requests-3] | 2024-02-05 12:00:58.731005 |  52.51.226.179 |       23415800 | 172.19.133.25
    Submitted 1 concurrent range requests [Native-Transport-Requests-3] | 2024-02-05 12:00:58.800005 |  52.51.226.179 |       23484490 | 172.19.133.25
    Submitted 1 concurrent range requests [Native-Transport-Requests-3] | 2024-02-05 12:00:58.868005 |  52.51.226.179 |       23553075 | 172.19.133.25
    Submitted 1 concurrent range requests [Native-Transport-Requests-3] | 2024-02-05 12:00:58.937006 |  52.51.226.179 |       23621760 | 172.19.133.25
    Submitted 1 concurrent range requests [Native-Transport-Requests-3] | 2024-02-05 12:00:59.006005 |  52.51.226.179 |       23690449 | 172.19.133.25
    Submitted 1 concurrent range requests [Native-Transport-Requests-3] | 2024-02-05 12:00:59.075004 |  52.51.226.179 |       23759378 | 172.19.133.25
    Submitted 1 concurrent range requests [Native-Transport-Requests-3] | 2024-02-05 12:00:59.144004 |  52.51.226.179 |       23828318 | 172.19.133.25
```

Number of concurrent requests depends on No. of cores * 10.
Due to single range requests(Submitted 1 concurrent range requests) in cassandra 4, the request queue is taking more time.

Any reason ?

Any suggested area to investigate ?